# FFmpeg Video Trimming and Audio Enhancement

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I started with a video that had unwanted material at beginning and end, and whose audio track was too quiet. I have ended up with one that is trimmed and audio-enhanced, but much smaller. I would appreciate advice on how to improve this process.

First command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:07.0 -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 02:00:00.0 -filter:a "volume=5dB" output.mp4
```

That produced an error:

```
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.
```

I re-ran that command without `-filter:a "volume=5db"` and that worked: output.mp4 started and ended at the desired points, and had the same video bitrate (but, for some reason, its audio bitrate increased by 10 kb/s). I renamed output.mp4 to be input.mp4 and ran this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:a "volume=5dB" output.mp4
```

That produced a new output.mp4 with somewhat louder sound, but now the video bitrate dropped from 5,000 kb/s to 999 kb/s, and the audio bitrate dropped from 161 to 129 kb/s. To my eye and ear, however, video and audio quality seemed unchanged.

**My question:** is there a single command that would trim video length and boost audio volume at the same time, without losing quality?

The recommended command would ideally resolve several problems in the approach I took:

- Presumably I would not want to see video bitrate drop so dramatically, unless perhaps FFmpeg detected that it could significantly cut video bitrate without losing appreciable quality. Recording the original at 5,000 kb/s was a guess; maybe it was overkill.
- Presumably the audio bitrate should remain constant; I don't understand the fluctuations.
- I guessed that 5db might be the right audio enhancement, but would prefer an option or method that wouldn't require guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

## Filtering requires re-encoding

Therefore you can't [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c copy`) and filter the same stream. However, you can stream copy the other, unfiltered streams such as the video in your case (`-c:v copy`).

---

## Accurate cutting/trimming is not guaranteed...

**...when using stream copy on typical MP4 video files**. With stream copy it can only cut on key frames. If the trim/cut is close enough or acceptable then you can ignore this.

If it is not accurate enough then you'll have to re-encode by omitting `-c copy` which will take much longer.

---

## Trim video length and boost audio without losing quality. Possible?

**Yes**. If you use lossless formats, but I doubt that's what you want. Lossless is generally huge and possibly not compatible with your target player/device.

**Yes**, if you use a player to do it: `ffplay -ss 7 -t 02:00:00 -af "volume=5dB" input.mp4`

**No**, if you need a lossy format such as AAC audio due to [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

---

## tl;dr

Use:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:07.0 -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -t 02:00:00.0 -filter:a "volume=5dB" output.mp4
```

If the cut is not accurate enough use:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:07.0 -i input.mp4 -t 02:00:00.0 -filter:a "volume=5dB" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I've been struggling to add a quality control element (e.g., -b:v 1M -pass 2) but so far no luck on that; no idea why the results were so variable before.

Comment: @RayWoodcock The defaults for libx264 are fairly good. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info if you are re-encoding.